# SET client_min_messages to specific ROLE postgres

Tags: postgresql, set, roles, pgadmin, postgresql-9.6

Hi Im trying to set the client_min_messages = error to a role using the postgres user, but when I login in the role I check current_setting('client_min_messages') and I get DEFAULT VALUE (notice). Ive already tried restarting config and also done some tests.

To summarize I did:

1. Login with postgres role.
2. check default values of client_min_messages(notice) and log_min_messages(warning).
3. ALTER ROLE anne SET client_min_messages = error;
4. ALTER ROLE anne SET log_min_messages = panic;
5. SELECT pg_reload_conf();
6. Logout postgres.
7. Login anne.
8. check SELECT current_setting('client_min_messages'), returning NOTICE(default value).
9. check SELECT current_setting('log_min_messages'), returning panic(non default value).
10. Test the code below

```
    begin;
        do $$
            begin
                raise info ' client_min_messages: %',current_setting('client_min_messages'); -- i get "notice"
                raise debug ' time : %', NOW(); 
                raise notice ' time : %', NOW(); 
                raise warning ' time : %', NOW(); 
        end $$;
```

I mean, I have to set client_min_messages every time I log with an user? So the Alter Role/User SET client_min_messages is useless?

I've tried changing login_min_messages to an specific role and when I login with the role the configuration remains ok(not default value).

Comment: @jjanes 
I did 

1. Login with postgres role.
2. check default values of client_min_messages(notice) and log_min_messages(warning).
3. ALTER ROLE anne  SET client_min_messages = error;
4. ALTER ROLE anne  SET log_min_messages = panic;
5. SELECT pg_reload_conf();
6. Logout postgres.
7. Login anne.
8. check SELECT current_setting('client_min_messages'), returning NOTICE(default value).
9. check SELECT current_setting('log_min_messages'), returning panic(non default value).
10. Test the code above.

Comment: Don't post additional information in comments. **[edit]** your question.

Comment: ok, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

The method should work. It worked for me.

Do you have any environment variables (like PGOPTIONS) set or explicit call out of the `set client_min_messages` command in the session?

Comment: Yeah, worked for me too.  An invocation of the SQL command `set client_min_messages...;` which over-rides the other setting could also be occurring in the .psqlrc file.  Another possibility is that there is an `ALTER ROLE anne IN DATABASE ...` in effect.  That will take priority over an ALTER ROLE with no DATABASE specified.  There are like 7 different ways to do this, and all of them except postgresql.conf will take priority over ALTER ROLE without IN DATABASE.