# Changing client_min_messages and log_min_messages

Tags: postgresql, set, roles, postgresql-9.6

Hi Im trying to change the default value of client_min_messages and log_min_messages from postgres user, it works in the session but then if I restart it comes back to default settings.

Do I need to do something extra?

Ive already tried with pg_reload_config, commiting, etc.

Comment: Isn't that the same question you already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61256250/

Comment: Its similar, but not the same. In the other question im asking about setting a specific parameter in a specific role. Now im asking for the database config.

Comment: So how **did** you change that default value? And which SQL client are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes I did. pgAdmin4.

Comment: and **how** did you change it? I don't use it, but maybe pgAdmin sets that after connecting

Answer (score 2):

Execute the following SQL statements as superuser:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET client_min_messages = ...;
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_min_messages = ...;
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Done!